# Trying to use grunt uncss to remove some css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gruntjs

I have a website that I inherited with a couple of gigantic css files that analysing with DUst-Me Selector in Firefox return me with almost 2000 unused styles.

To remove them I'm trying to use grunt uncss, the problem is that I get the following error:

```
grunt uncss
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
Fatal error: uncss/node_modules/css: missing '}' near line 2429:5
 ->     .mobile-hidden {
```

Those are my configuration files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tappr-registration",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-processhtml": "^0.3.3",
    "grunt-uncss": "^0.3.7"
     }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uncss: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                media: ['min-width'],
                timeout: 1000,
                htmlroot: 'public_html',
                report: 'max'
            },
            files: {
                'dist/clean.css': ['public_html/index.php',     'public_html/page_2.html', 'public_html/page_3.html']
            }
        }
    }
});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uncss" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss','processhtml']);
};
```

Now, my best guess is that I get this error because I specifying in the wrong way the media queries to include but I haven't found some decent documentation on how uncss wants that option.

I already tried to take off the options.

Do somebody has some good suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not the problem was caused by the comments:

```
<!-- ----- Responsive 34.2857142857em ------>
```

After that I remove them everything worked fine and I can say the it was very much needed.

```
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
File cleancss/tidy.css created: 229.48 kB → 25.98 kB
```

:)